# How to protect a card from RL damage (scratches, bends, cracks) and still play them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, card-sleeves

I playing MTG for 17 years now. At first, I tried to protect my cards with simple thin sleeves and create/modify my deck without even considering the RL price of my cards. Now

I play EDH mostly. I really want to add [Time Spiral](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Spiral) to my Izzet Commander, but I do not want it to lose its condition ( it's already Played (PL) ). Nowadays I use protectors sleeves, mostly from Dragon Shield, but I think it may be not enough.
I know that I can't use extra layers, because it will allow distinguishing that card from the deck easily. I'm not a fan of proxy cards either.

I just want to know how others solve this kind of problem. Thanks in advance for Your answers!

Comment: What's preventing you from double-sleeving your whole deck?

Comment: @philip-kendall good question. EDH deck is 100 cards. Adding an additional layer will make it less comfortable to shuffle it - yet not unplayable. It is a good way to protect all cards tho. But there are two issues: You need to have twice as many sleeves as cards (protectors + sleeves) or remove both layers every time You modify Your deck (which occurs quite frequently in my case). Call me lazy, but if I had to choose between money or comfort, I will always choose comfort. Still, buying 5k+ of sleeves (for all cards in my collection) seems costly. Only for cards that I use would make sense. :)

Comment: You don't need to buy sleeves for every card in you collection, just those that you've put in decks this (month / year / decade)

Comment: https://cardboard-crack.com/post/51935512772/iphone-deck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't point to any scientific backup, my personal experience and experimentation ended in me double-sleeving all of my decks. In addition to gaining protection from all six sides rather than just five of them, you will also in the vast majority of cases end up with waterproof cards, and due to the additional rigidity, they at least feel like they wouldn't bend as easily (though of course, it is only thin layers of plastic we're talking about here, so it will never be able to withstand any serious attempt at damaging the card).

On the point of shuffling, if you're used to shuffling sleeved decks without using force, double-sleeving a deck doesn't add a whole lot of difficulty to it, even for Commander-sized decks. I could see that for players with small hands, it could potentially be more difficult, but in any case, I would recommend just trying it a few times (maybe with another person's deck), and you will quickly see whether it's for you.

While it surely is personal preference, I found that the combination of KMC Perfect Fit inner sleeves and Ultra Pro Pro-Matte outer sleeves work best for me.

As discussed in the comments, it isn't feasible to do that to your entire collection, which you might assume if what you're doing is using penny sleeves to store cards - this is merely a suggestion for cards that will actually be played, and therefore are actually exposed to wear. Generally speaking, the cost for double-sleeving a deck will be much lower than having to replace even one medium-priced card for an EDH deck. That is certainly the case for [Time Spiral](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Spiral), which at the time of writing I would have to pay around 120 bucks for. In my opinion, it makes more sense to think about it that way, rather than paying for double sleeves to protect a lot of Islands.

Answer (score -1):

Commander is supposed to be a casual format, so if your play group is agreeable, there's nothing stopping you from playing a proxy card.

Comment: +1 from me. Not sure what the downvotes are for. Proxying a card, especially if you can show that you have an actual copy, seems perfectly reasonable to me. We had a person in our playgroup who had a dozen commander decks and they proxied some of the more expensive cards that they wanted to play in multiple decks. Making them switch cards between decks each time they changed their decks would have been an unnecessary waste of time that can be spent playing the game instead.

Comment: @SwimmerF The downvotes likely are due to the answer not being useful in answering how to protect a card from damage, similar to how someone asking "How do I not get wet in the rain?" probably wouldn't want to hear "Just stay home". Additionally, the user posting the question specifically stated that they don't want to use proxies.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I admit I didn't notice "I'm not a fan of proxies", but otherwise, "use a proxy" absolutely is a useful answer of how to protect a card from damage. If someone asks "How do I not get wet while getting groceries?", I would consider "Get groceries delivered" to be a perfectly valid answer (one might have objections to it, such as "That would be more expensive", but an answer having drawbacks is different from it not being a valid answer).

Comment: @TheThirdMan Even if the answer is not useful to the OP themselves, I think the suggestion of proxies has merit, since "not using the card protects the card" might not occur to some people.

Comment: I see what the two of you are saying, and it could absolutely be a useful answer for someone. I'll still stand by my point, especially since the question caption specifically reads "How to protect a card [...] and still play them?"